# Google Spreadsheets script - How to copy range from one sheet to another sheet, but without overwriting non-empty target cells

Tags: javascript, for-loop, google-apps-script, google-sheets, copy

I'm trying to copy certain cells from sheet 1 (source sheet) to sheet 2 (target sheet), without deleting existing cells in sheet 2.

I want to copy A5:A800 from sheet 1 to C7:C802 from sheet 2.

**Conditions:**

- One-to-one copying: So for example, content of cell A25 goes to cell
  C27.
- No overwriting: if C27 already has a value or text, it should stay like that. A25 doesn't get copied. The script should skip non-empty cells.
- A cell with a zero should not be considered as an empty cell.

**My usage**

I will add the script to a 'button'. My sheet 1 keeps getting updated automatically. Sometimes I manually change cells in sheet 2. I don't want those changes to be overwritten when I press the button (run the script).

```
function CopyCells() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  
  var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("sheet1"); //source sheet
  var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName("sheet2"); //target sheet

  //missing for loop magic
  
  var getCopyRange = sheet1.getRange("A5:A800");
  getCopyRange.copyTo(sheet2.getRange("C7:C802"));

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation:

- My approach would be to get the data of `sheet2` and use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to fill in the empty values with the values of `sheet1`:

  ```
  vals2.map((v,i)=>[v==''?vals1[i]:v]);
  ```

  For the non-empty values keep the original values.
- I also added an `onOpen()` function to create a menu button linked to the `CopyCells` function.
- I use a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator#:%7E:text=The%20conditional%20(ternary)%20operator%20is,if%20the%20condition%20is%20falsy.) to simplify the code and I [flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)ten the values from the sheets since we consider values of a column and therefore a `1D` array makes more sense.

### Solution:

```
function CopyCells() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("sheet1"); //source sheet
  const sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName("sheet2"); //target sheet
  const range1 = sheet1.getRange('A5:A800');
  const range2 = sheet2.getRange('C7:C802');
  const vals1 = range1.getValues().flat();
  const vals2 = range2.getValues().flat();
  const fvals = vals2.map((v,i)=>[v==''?vals1[i]:v]);
  range2.clearContent();
  range2.setValues(fvals);
}
 
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
  .createMenu('Button')
  .addItem('Copy Cells', 'CopyCells')
  .addToUi();
}
```

Comment: It does the job very well. Thank you very much.